# How to re-establish SQL Server mirror

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-mirroring

I have a question regarding database mirroring. I've tried reading the documentation, I think I understand it, but - it's a production database and I really don't want to mess this up!!

I have a primary server - called `COMPANYSQL` - with the primary database. In SQL Server Manager it says `DBNAME (Principal, Disconnected)`.

I have a backup server - called `COMPANYREMOTE` - with the one-way mirror of the database for failover purposes. It says `DBNAME (Mirrored, Suspended / Restoring)`.

To re-establish the mirror, I think I can right click on the `COMPANYREMOTE` database, choose `Tasks > Launch Database Mirroring Manager`.

The I see under the Database Mirroring Monitor:

```
DBNAME (Suspended, COMPANYSQL->COMPANYREMOTE\MIRRORED-DBNAME).
```

I can right click and choose "Register Mirrored Database".

From here I get confused. It tells me to select the principal DB, so from the first dropdown I choose `COMPANYSQL` and the primary database (`DBNAME`) appears in the list. Current role is Principal and Partner (Connect As) is `COMPANYREMOTE\MIRRORED-DBNAME`.

I think if I hit Ok here...it'll re-establish the mirror?

Just don't want to mirror it the other way by mistake and overwrite anything on my production.

THANKS!

Comment: is it Asynchronise Mirroring ? What I am trying to get at is do you have a witness server ?

Comment: no Witness server, just two SQL servers - the first server is the Principal with the production database, and the 2nd server is just a copy (for manual failover purposes only)

Answer (score 1):

Run below mention command in Principal Node

Alter database DBNAME set partner resume

Thanks,
Mani

Answer (score 0):

Eh, no responses, it's ok.  I got some advice and it turns out it's best to delete the mirror and re-create it when it gets messed up. In my case, there was approximately 30GB of unsent data that was going to take forever to mirror so it chokes out.